# App isn't installed on your device error in very first program

Tags: android, android-studio

There seem to be too many bugs which have not been properly documented, regarding android studio. I am trying to run a basic Hello world app, and this error is truly making me give up any more efforts.

What I did:
Open Android studio(also tried running as administrator) and tried to run the default Hello world app on an Android 10 device(Xiaomi). At the start it shows Failed to start monitoring 7D8XXCOJGQQCZLJV(device number). At first I ignored it being a beginner and clicked on the run button. The file was successfully built and the RUN section shows 'Install successfully finished'.

Now for clarity here are some screenshots that will display what happened on my android device after the above steps:
[image: I clicked on Install button in this step]

The app seemed to be installed correctly, but whenever I click on the app logo the response I get is really frustrating:
[image: It keeps showing app not installed!]

As per the this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers) I tried to go to the device manager and do some changes, by setting and enabling Xiaomi drivers for Portable devices.
[image: The usb_driver folder contains the drives for Xiaomi devices]

But then windows shows:
[image]

If anybody knows how to solve this, please do help me in doing so. It is quite discouraging to experience so many errors, right at the beginning. If somebody could give a working solution then that would really help me in continuing my android journey.

Answer (score 8):

There was just a tiny error that led to this entire problem. This was because I had set the value of android:exported="false" in the main activity, which had to be set to true. Hope that this may help anybody in the future!

Answer (score 0):

set the value of android:exported="true" in the AndroidManifest